# Could not retrieve local facts: closed stream

Tags: device, puppet, net-ssh

Has anyone every come across the following error when trying to use "puppet device" against cisco devices?

Could not retrieve local facts: closed stream

Its only happening on a few select devices but I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting the exception? or whats throwing it? Im pretty sure its something to do with how puppet is using ruby's net-ssh gem? But i cant confirm this. Ive also tried all kinds of net-ssh version but still get the same error.

Comment: After some investigation it looks like the line causing it is in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb line number 110:
 
loop { channels.any? }

Does anyone have any ideas why this is causing the "closed stream" error? It seems channels.any? does return true. Not sure why i get the exception though?

Comment: On a device that has always worked without the "closed stream" exception the channels.any? returns true also?